# Setting File Associations with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, file-association

When setting up a File Association for my App with ClickOnce I run into an issue. I'm using the Properties > Publish > Options > File Associations method. The issue is that when I try to set the default icon for that file I get the "Icon is not set to be published with the application, or is not part of the required download group" error. After some searching I seem to be stuck. How does one set up an association, and more specifically how do you add an icon to the project and reference it in the File Association manager?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that your **icon file is part of the Application Files** (Publish > Application Files). In my case I needed to change the **type of the icon file to 'Content'** and then it showed up in the list of Application Files. Then I was able to specify the file association without any errors.

Comment: This worked very well! I do have another question following this path. Now that the file association is made. How is it that upon double clicking the project file of my app (in my case .bep) that it opens the App? I had assumed adding the association and then publishing would automatically set that up, but I appear to be wrong.

Comment: I haven't progressed that far myself either. I'll let you know when I find out. BTW, how about an upvote ;-)

Comment: Yeah, can do! Also, I'll let you know if I happen to stumble upon it as well.